# When using 'requests.get()', the html is less than the actual html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

[image]

[image]

The first image is the html of the site brought in python, and the second image is the actual html viewed by pressing F12 on the site. I don't know why the two results are different. Other sites display html normally, but I wonder why only that site is not displayed normally.

Here is the Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get('https://www.overbuff.com/heroes')

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Comment: because the response is `" the page you are trying to reach is temporarily unavailable. please try again later "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your maybe blocked by the page and should try it with some `headers` like:

```
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}    
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.overbuff.com/heroes"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Comment: Just changing the user agent didn't work for me, but I got it working after copying all the headers from the browser request. It looks like that site is using multiple header fields to detect bots.